# How to let SonarQube be aware of tests in different directories

Tags: sonarqube, cloudbees

I have created a specific isolated directory for selenium tests in my project as well as integration tests.

What sonar properties need to change to let SonarQube be aware of the location of the integration testing classes ? Also, is it possible to provide more than one directory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sonar.tests: Comma-separated paths to directories containing tests.
See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters